# visual studio 2010 Getting value from gridview

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

How do I get the value in a gridview when one hits the "Select" link in a row?

If I have a databound, I can get that value. However I am trying to highlight certain labels.The "HighlightTex" function lets me highlight some words that the user selects.

Here is a snippet: I am trying to get the value of "lblinvnum".

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server"     AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True"
AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"     Width="540px" 
        CssClass="Gridview" >
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#df5015" />
<Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Invnum"     ItemStyle-Wrap="False">
   <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="lblInvnum" Text='<%#     HighlightText(Eval("Invnum").ToString()) %>' runat="server"     />
   </ItemTemplate>
```

...
...
... For the "AmtPaid" listed below, I can Get that value. I cannot figure out how to get the value for "lblInvnum" to the snippet listed above.

```
       <asp:BoundField DataField="AmtPaid" HeaderText="AmtPaid" 
        SortExpression="AmtPaid" DataFormatString="{0:c}" >
```

In visual basic, this is how I can get the one above for AmtPaid.

```
        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        Dim selectedRow As GridViewRow = gvDetails.Rows(index)
        Dim contactCell As TableCell = selectedRow.Cells(1)
        Dim contact As String = contactCell.Text
```

Suggestions?

Comment: What does this have to do with visual studio? Is this an add-in?

Comment: SOLVED-I added DataKeyNames to ..... CssClass="Gridview" DataKeyNames="invnum" > to gvDetails then in ...Protected Sub gvDetails_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gvDetails.SelectedIndexChanged ... I added ... strInvnum2 = Trim(gvDetails.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString).... I hope this will help somebody else...